# Keyboard pushing up buttons in Stack

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do I add a scrollView without covering everything else up. I added .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) to the outer Stack to stop the keyboard from pushing my buttons at the bottom up but when I try to add a scrollView all that is displayed is the confirm and back buttons and navigation title and none of the form I want the user to scroll through and fill out

```
import SwiftUI

struct NewEventView: View{
    
    @State private var newEventName: String = ""
    @State private var newEventAddress: String = ""
    @State private var newEventPrivacy: String = ""
    @State private var newEventMaxAttendents: String = ""
    @State private var newEventPrice: String = ""
    @State private var newEventNotes: String = ""
    @State private var newEventStartTime = Date.now
    @State private var newEventEndTime = Date()
    @State private var newEventStartDate = Date.now
    @State private var newEventEndDate = Date()
    @State private var newEventType: String = ""
    
    
    var body: some View{
        
        
        VStack{
            Text("New Event")
            List(){
                HStack{
                    Text("Event Name:   ")
                    TextField("Name", text: $newEventName)
                }
                HStack{
                    Text("Address:         ")
                    TextField("Address", text: $newEventAddress)
                }
                HStack{
                    Picker(selection: $newEventPrivacy, label: Text("Privacy:         ")) {
                        Text("Public ").tag("1")
                        Text("Private").tag("2")
                    }
                    .fixedSize()
                    .scaledToFit()
                }
                HStack{
                    Text("Attendance:    ")
                    TextField("Max Attendents", text: $newEventMaxAttendents)
                }
                HStack{
                    DatePicker("Start Date    ", selection: $newEventStartDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
                }
                .scaledToFit()
                HStack{
                    DatePicker("Start Time    ", selection: $newEventStartTime, displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute])
                }
                .scaledToFit()
                HStack{
                    DatePicker("End Date      ", selection: $newEventEndDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
                }
                .scaledToFit()
                HStack{
                    DatePicker("End Time      ", selection: $newEventEndTime, displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute])
                }
                .scaledToFit()
                HStack{
                    Text("Price               ")
                    TextField("Price", text: $newEventPrice)
                }
                HStack{
                    Picker(selection: $newEventType, label: Text("Type            ")) {
                        Text("Private   ").tag("1")
                        Text("Education ").tag("2")
                        Text("Concert   ").tag("3")
                        Text("Festival  ").tag("4")
                        Text("Food      ").tag("5")
                        Text("Religious ").tag("6")
                        Text("Attraction").tag("7")
                        Text("Business  ").tag("8")
                    }
                    .fixedSize()
                }
            }
                // HStack for confirm and cancel buttons
                HStack{
                    // BASH button
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Confirm")
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Confirm")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                            .background{
                                Color.red
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                    .shadow(radius: 5)
                            }
                    }) // confirm button
                    
                    // back button
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Back")
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Text("  Back   ")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                            .background{
                                Color.red
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                    .shadow(radius: 5)
                            }
                    }) // BASH button
                } // HStack for confirm and back buttons
            } // VStack
            .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
        } // View
        
    }
```

Comment: This is built in feature of SwiftUI framework which provides seamless and intuitive experience for the user. Framework automatically adjust the space according to the selected TextField so that you can interact the views easily which is called "adaptive layout".

Comment: @TYPLERB. Please update your code to show a _minimal_ example that reproduces the issue; ideally a `struct ContentView` that someone can paste into Xcode and run. Please take a look at [mcve]